# MSProject: Insert SubProject after Task x? (Linking ConsolidateProjects to Task)

Tags: vba, vb.net, ms-office, ms-project

I have to solve the task of **dynamically inserting Sub-Projects** into a Master-Project **at a specific position** - which is under a certain "heading" and after all the already inserted SubProjects.

```
Heading A
Heading Aa
- Project A1
- Project A2
Heading B
- Project B1
```

**My problem is that ConsolidateProjects inserts the subproject at the current cursor position**.
Now I solved it like that:

- collapse / expand all Tasks so that Headings and Subheadings are visible but all Subtasks of Sub-Projects are hidden
- iterate through rows with SelectRow, get task-name with ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Name
- if it's the right heading, get number of already inserted subprojects with Tasks(from_last_step).OutlineChildren.Count
- Call ConsolidateProjects
- Indent the new inserted project to the correct level

This solution has shown to be very error-prone. The initial indent of the new subproject seems quite random and often the subprojects and up at the wrong position.

**Isn't there any solution like "Insert subproject after Task(x), no matter in which row it is displayed at the moment"?**
Or anyone has another idea?

Hope somebody has help!

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?